# C: finding the number of elements in an array[]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In C:
How do you find the number of elements in an array of structs, after sending it to a function?

```
int main(void) {
  myStruct array[] = { struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5, struct6 };
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(array));
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(array[0]));
  f(array);
}
void f(myStruct* array) {
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(array));
  printf("%d\n", sizeof(array[0]));
}
```

For some reason the printf in main shows different results than the printf in f.
My need is to know how many elements are in the array.

Comment: Because `sizeof()` is a compile-time operator and not a member function (as in C++).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't.

You have to pass the size to the function, eg:

```
void f(myStruct* array, size_t siz);
```

Also notice that in `f` array is a pointer, while in `main` it is an array. Arrays and pointers are different things.

Comment: Why use `size_t`? Couldn't you just use an integer for array length, or is that not safe somehow?

Comment: @Christian Mann: Several reasons, including: the type of the value returned by `sizeof` is `size_t`; array sizes can never be negative, so it makes sense to use an unsigned type for the array size; `size_t` is guaranteed to be wide enough to hold the maximum number of bytes that can be allocated at any one time, whereas `int` is not (IOW, if an array of T can contain 2^64 bytes, then `size_t` is guaranteed to be 64 bits wide, but `int` is only guaranteed to be at least 16 bits wide);

Comment: An alternative to passing around size is to NULL-terminate the array, a time-tested solution, but this only works if you have an array of pointers (which is more common than an array of arrays in C).

Answer (score 10):

In f `array` is a pointer, in main `array` is an array.

Comment: And once you have a pointer you can't determine the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You must pass that data as a separate parameter to the function. In C and C++ as soon as an array is passed to a function the array degenerates into a pointer. Pointers have no notion of how many elements are in the array they point to.

A common way to get the size is to declare the array and then immediately get the array element count by dividing the total size by the size of one element. Like this:

```
struct my_struct my_struct_array[] = {
 {"data", 1, "this is data"},
 {"more data", 2, "this is more data"},
 {"yet more", 0, "and again more data"}
};
const size_t my_struct_array_count = sizeof(my_struct_array)/sizeof(my_struct_array[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [C reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) says, you cannot do this unless either the last element is unique or you pass a count of array elements to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in main(), array refers to the actual array and so sizeof() gives the required answer.

But when you pass it as function parameter,you are actually passing the address of the first element of the array which is stored in the pointer variable 'array'.
So now sizeof() gives the size of pointer variable which is why it differs from actual answer.

Possible solution can be to

1.Declare the array globally

2.Pass the array size as function parameter
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, function f() has no way of knowing how many elements were in your original array. It's a feature of the language and there's no way around it. You'll have to pass the length.

Answer (score 1):

you have to end the array with a special value and in called function you have to count up to that value that is how strlen() works it counts up to NULL '\0' value.

Comment: That is certainly one solution, but it's not the only one.

Comment: you are sending the function a pointer (an address in memory) how will it count, if it does not know where it is ending. There is no array type in C as we know in higher languages. You can create an array class in C++ which also stores its size (or use allready defined ones)

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell number of elements in an array in **C** consistently. Specially if you pass the array around through pointers.

Usually, if you **must** use array size in a function, pass it as a parameter to it.

Comment: The number of elements in an array is always given by `sizeof array / sizeof array[0]`. As long as the array is an honest-to-god array it is very easy :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `sizeof` in `main`, it's evaluating the array, and gives the size of the actual array.

When you use `sizeof` in `f`, you've passed the name of the array as an argument to a function, so it has decayed to a pointer, so `sizeof` tells you about the size of a pointer.

Generally speaking, if you pass an array to a function, you need to either write the function to only work with one specific size of array, or explicitly pass the size of array for it to work with on a particular invocation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a format for your array. I am using string elements, it should work for struct.

```
#define NULL ""
#define SAME 0

static char *check[] = {
      "des", "md5", "des3_ede", "rot13", "sha1", "sha224", "sha256",
      "blowfish", "twofish", "serpent", "sha384", "sha512", "md4", "aes",
      "cast6", "arc4", "michael_mic", "deflate", "crc32c", "tea", "xtea",
      "khazad", "wp512", "wp384", "wp256", "tnepres", "xeta",  "fcrypt",
      "camellia", "seed", "salsa20", "rmd128", "rmd160", "rmd256", "rmd320",
      "lzo", "cts", "zlib", NULL
 }; // 38 items, excluding NULL
```

in main ( )

```
char **algo = check;
int numberOfAlgo = 0;


while (SAME != strcmp(algo[numberOfAlgo], NULL)) {
    printf("Algo: %s \n", algo[numberOfAlgo++]);
}

printf("There are %d algos in the check list. \n", numberOfAlgo);
```

You should get the output:

```
Algo: des 
   :
   :
Algo: zlib 

There are 38 algos in the check list.
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to use the  **NULL** , do this instead:

```
numberOfAlgo = 0;

while (*algo) {
    printf("Algo: %s \n", *algo);
    algo++;         // go to the next item
    numberOfAlgo++; // count the item
}

printf("There are %d algos in the check list. \n", numberOfAlgo);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an example to your solution:

Given

```
struct contain {
char* a;        //
int allowed;    //

struct suit {
   struct t {
          char* option;
          int count;
   } t;

   struct inner {
          char* option;
          int count;
   } inner;
} suit;
};
```

// eg. initialized

```
     struct contain structArrayToBeCheck[] = {
    {
        .a = "John",
        .allowed = 1,

        .suit = {
            .t = {
                .option = "ON",
                .count = 7
            },

            .inner = {
                .option = "OFF",
                .count = 7
            }
        }
    },
    {
        .a = "John",
        .allowed = 1,

        .suit = {
            .t = {
                .option = "ON",
                .count = 7
            },

            .inner = {
                .option = "OFF",
                .count = 7
            }
        }
    },
    {
        .a = "John",
        .allowed = 1,

        .suit = {
            .t = {
                .option = "ON",
                .count = 7
            },

            .inner = {
                .option = "OFF",
                .count = 7
            }
        }
    },
    {
        .a = "John",
        .allowed = 1,

        .suit = {
            .t = {
                .option = "ON",
                .count = 7
            },

            .inner = {
                .option = "OFF",
                .count = 7
            }
        }
    }

};
```

in main()

```
printf("Number of Struct within struct array: %d \n", sizeof(structArrayToBeCheck)/sizeof(struct contain));
```

gives you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int array[10]

int Number_of_elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

printf("%d", Number_of_elements);
```