# Objective C - Summarize elements in int array

Tags: c, arrays, integer, sum

Ok so i have an int array that looks like this:

```
int money[] = {};
```

and then I added values to that array by doing scanf, and then added each scanf value to the array with a for-loop, ONE number at a time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    money[i] = currentPrice;
}
```

So after doing this a few times (with scanf) my array looks like this:

```
money[] = {50, 75, 1, 40, 4};
```

How can I use a for-loop to go through all elements in the list and add them together and print them out?

```
int total = blablabla.......
printf(total);
```

Comment: Does objective-C allow zero size arrays? Because that isn't standard C.

Comment: Is this a C or Objective-C question? You cant dynamically resize C arrays since they are just contiguous blocks of memory, and you aren't using `NSMutableArray` and `NSNumber` which would be the easier solution if you want to use Obj-C

Comment: I tried writing NSArray money = {} but it did not work. How do I do that? And how would I add numbers to the array, using scanf?

Answer (score -1):

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++) {
    total += money[i];
}

printf("%i", total);
```

Note that you need to keep a reference to the number of ints in your array.

Also I must point out that your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    money[i] = currentPrice;
}
```

Is not adding a value to the array it is just rewriting the value `currentPrice` to the 0th index of the array. Therefore your array will never have a length > 1.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)

Here is a basic example of adding ints to an array using scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_COUNT 10

int myArr[10];
int currentCount = 0;

void addInt();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++) {
        addInt();
    }
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++) {
        total += myArr[i];
    }
    printf("%i", total);

    return 0;
}

void addInt() {
    int new;
    scanf("Enter num: %i", &new);
    myArr[currentCount] = new;
    // Keep reference of number of elements in array...
    currentCount++;
}
```

Comment: how do I get the arrayCount?

Comment: When you "add" a value to the array you need to have another int that tracks the count (easiest option). See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290610/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array) for more details.

Comment: That website is blocked in my country. Can you please provide a code example instead, on how to add integer values to the array, using scanf?