# Parameters in the sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, sizeof

I understand that when we use `sizeof` operator on an array name, it gives the total size of the array in bytes. For example

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int a[][5] = {
        {1,2,3,4,5},
        {10,20,30,40,50},
        {100,200,300,400,500}
    };

    int n=sizeof(a);
    printf("%d\n",n);

}
```

It gives `60` as output for `15 elements` of the array. But when I write

```
int n=sizeof(*a);
```

It gives `20` as the output that is the size of the first row while `*a` is the base address of the `0th` element of the `0th` row, and its type is a pointer to an integer. And `a` points to the first row itself. Why is this happening?

Comment: @user202729 fair enough.

Comment: probably a duplicate lurking somewhere

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The *expression* `a` has type "3-element array of 5-element array of `int`"; thus, `sizeof a` should yield `3 * 5 * sizeof (int)`.

The expression `*a` is the same as the expression `a[0]` (`a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - `*a` is the same as `*(a + 0)`, which is the same as `a[0]`).  Both `*a` and `a[0]` have type "5-element array of `int`"; thus `sizeof *a` and `sizeof a[0]` should both yield `5 * sizeof (int)`.

However...

If you pass `a` to a function, such as

```
foo( a );
```

then `a` is *not* the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, and the expression will be converted from type "3-element array of 5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 5-element array of `int`":

```
void foo( int (*a)[5] ) { ... }
```

If you computed `sizeof a` in function `foo`, you would *not* get `5 * sizeof (int)`, you would get `sizeof (int (*)[5])`, which, depending on the platform, would be 4 to 8 bytes.

Similarly, if you passed `*a` or `a[i]` to a function, what the function actually receives is a pointer to `int`, not an array of `int`, and `sizeof` will reflect that.

Comment: What if we pass a and print the sizeof(*a) ? In this case it is again giving 20 !

Comment: @GauravMishra: Remember, `a` "decays" to "pointer to 5-element array of `int`"; when you dereference it with `*a`, the type of the result is "5-element array of `int`".

Comment: Can you please tell me how to calculate the size of the whole array in the function when we pass a pointer to it ?  void foo( int (*a)[5] ) { ... }

Comment: @GauravMishra: You can’t.  That information is lost as part of the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

`*a` is row 0 of `a`, and that row is an array of five `int`.

In most expressions, an array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. Thus, when you use `*a` in a statement such as `int *x = *a;`, `*a` is converted to a pointer to its first element. That results in a pointer to `int`, which may be assigned to `x`.

However, when an array is the operand of a `sizeof` operator, a unary `&` operator, or an `_Alignof_` operator, it is not converted to a pointer to its first element. Also, an array that is a string literal being used to initialize an array is not converted to a pointer (so, in `char foo[] = "abc";`, `"abc"` is used as an array to initialize `foo`; it is not converted to a pointer).

Answer (score 4):

`*a` is not a pointer, it's an `int[5]`, which is coherent with your reading of `20` assuming a 4-byte `int`.

Comment: You can check the type of *a. It is int *

Comment: @GauravMishra if observing the size is not enough for you, you can convince yourself by taking its address and storing it in another variable. `int **p = &*a;` won't compile, but `int (*p)[5] = &*a;` will.

Comment: When I write printf("%d",*a) the compiler is saying "Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type int * " . Also when you use &*a together you get the variable itself . In this case you get a which is of type pointer to a 1d array !

Comment: @GauravMishra that's because passing an array as parameter to a function decays it into a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you . Please explain as I am confused !

Answer (score 0):

In this `2d` array `*a` is a pointer because when you print it, its seems an address (but it is the `1st` column address) :

```
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

Output : `9435248`

So :

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    printf("%d\n", *a[i]);
```

The output is :

```
1
10
100
```

When you use of `*a` like this : `*a[3]` its means you are in `3rd` row and `1st` column by default.

`*a` is the address of  `1st` column and we have `5` column, so when you try this :

```
sizeof(*a);
```

Output will be `20` => (`5` column) * (`int pointer` which is `4` byte)).

Answer (score 0):

A 2D array is viewed as an array of 1D arrays. That is, each row in a 2D array is a 1D array. For a given 2D array A, int A[m][n]
you can think of

- A[0] as the address of row 0
- A[1] as the address of row 1 etc & so on.

Dereferencing can be thought of as below,

```
 A[i][j] = *(A[i] + j) = *(*(A+i) + j)
```

So when you say *A, it means A[0] which gives you the address of 1st row & not the 1st element of the matrix.

- Dereference of A or *A gives the address of row 0 or A[0].
- Dereference of A[0] gives the first entry of A or A[0][0] that is

  **A = A[0][0].

& since you have 5 elements in the 1st row the size if 20 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Sizeof returns the size of the variable in memory expressed in bytes. This includes padding (unused bytes added by a compiler to a structure to improve performance). Your array has 15 elements of size 4. The sizeof an integer in memory is 4 in you case. You can easily verify this by running:

```
printf("sizeof an integer: %zu\n", sizeof(int));
```

It is always a good idea to use standard int types.

```
#inlcude <stdint.h>
uint32_t a[][5] = {
    {1,2,3,4,5},
    {10,20,30,40,50},
    {100,200,300,400,500}
};
```

This will produce exactly the same code but wil clearly show the memory size of the (32 bit) integer.
In your case uint8_t (unsigned int of 8 bit) might be more appropriate. You can read more [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html). To get the number of elements you should devide the total memory of the array by the sizeof an element.

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])
```

You can also use a macro to do this:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array)(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
/*ARRAY_LENGTH(a) will return 15 as expected.*/
```

You can also look for an answer here: [How can I find the number of elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290610/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array)

Comment: `printf("sizeof an integer: %ld\n", sizeof(int));` is undefined behavior. The proper format string modifier for `size_t` - what `sizeof()` returns - is `"z"`, so for decimal output `printf("sizeof an integer: %zd\n", sizeof(int));` would be correct.

Comment: The question asks about `sizeof(*a)`. This answer does not speak to that at all.