# C - how to loop through a char**

Tags: c

I have an array of strings which is `char**`. It has 4 elements, and when I try to find the number of elements using `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`, it always return 1 which leads to for loop unable to loop through all the elements in the `char**`.

```
char** departmentList;

departmentList = malloc(sizeof(*departmentList)); // allocate

getAllDepartments(departmentList, recordsPtr[0], numOfDepartments);

printf("%d",sizeof(departmentList)/sizeof(departmentList[0])); // return 1

printf("%d",sizeof(departmentList[0])); // return 8
```

`sizeof(departmentList)` yields 8 too.

Comment: You cannot get the size of a pointed to array from a pointer. You need to store the length explicitly somewhere

Comment: ...or store flag value NULL as the final element of the array

Comment: dupe of [How can I find the number of elements in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290610/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-elements-in-an-array) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should call a malloc explicitly to make sure the compiler knows the length of each "string". You allocated just the pointer which points to another pointer...